# Server not sending HTTP 101 response when creating a websocket using CC3000 and socket.io

Tags: websocket, socket.io, arduino, websocket++

I am connecting CC3000 to a node.js server using socket.io. I have used the following library to create a websocket
https://github.com/chadstachowicz/socket_io_arduino_cc3000

In SocketIOClient.cpp, it creates a TCP connection, gets a session-id(sid). It disconnects and creates another TCP connection and uses the sid to upgrade the connection to websocket. For this the client(here CC3000) sends the following header information:

```
client.print(F("GET /socket.io/1/websocket/"));
client.print(sid);
client.println(F(" HTTP/1.1"));
client.print(F("Host: "));
client.println(hostname);
client.println(F("Origin: ArduinoSocketIOClient"));
client.println(F("Upgrade: WebSocket"));    // must be camelcase ?!
client.println(F("Connection: Upgrade\r\n"));
```

After this request the client waits for HTTP 101 response from the server. But the server is not sending any response. It logs as warning "**websocket connection invalid**" and ends the connection.

Is the protocol for creating websocket fine or is there any missing information in the header?

Also, I want to know what should the value of 'Origin' be? During first handshake it is "Arduino" whereas in the second handshake it is "ArduinoSocketIOClient".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `Sec-WebSocket-Key` and `Sec-WebSocket-Version` headers, key part of the [WebSocket protocol handshake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket#WebSocket%5fprotocol%5fhandshake).

This is how an actual handshake looks:

```
GET /chat HTTP/1.1
Host: server.example.com
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Key: x3JJHMbDL1EzLkh9GBhXDw==
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: chat, superchat
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Origin: http://example.com
```

Comment: The library which I have used states that "This library doesn't support every inch of the Websocket spec, most notably the use of a Sec-Websocket-Key." Even though i tried using Sec-Wesocket-Key but it had no effect.

Comment: You cannot establish a websocket connection without that headers. Origin can be anything, is up to the server to accept that origin or not.